# Is there a way to do conditional data validation in Google Sheets / App Scripts from a listed data source?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a data validation drop down list in column C (laptop model) that is based on the input in column B (laptop make). I have been able to figure this out by splitting the different laptop models into different tables and using the script below.

```
function onEdit(){
  var hardwaretab = "Hardware";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(hardwaretab);
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 2 && activeCell.getRow() <20 && ss.getSheetName() == hardwaretab){
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    
  var makes = ss.getRange(29, 1, 1, ss.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Logger.log(makes)  
    var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
  Logger.log(makeIndex)  
    if(makeIndex != 0){
    
        var validationRange = ss.getRange(30, makeIndex, ss.getLastRow());
        Logger.log(validationRange)
        var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
        activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
     }  
      
  }
  
}
```

what I would really like is to be able to achieve the same result from an individual table instead of having to split the bands as the next step is a vlookup and I would prefer not to use a complicated IF statement (although this is currently what I have).

I am sure there is a way to use the filter function in Apps script however I haven't been able to figure it out.

Below shows a rough example of the data source I am after

```
Apple   MacBook Pro 13inch 2020
Apple   MacBook Pro 16-inch 
Apple   MacBook Pro 14inch 2021
Apple   MacBook Pro 16inch 2021
Apple   iMac 27
Dell    Latitude 3590
Dell    Latitude 5250
Dell    Latitude 5450
Dell    Latitude 5550
Dell    Latitude 7280
Dell    Latitude 7350
Lenovo  Thinkpad
```

Comment: I provided you with a more compact version of your code which makes bettter use of the event object.   At first you may not like it because you cannot run it from the script editor.  Beyond that I don't understand what you your issue is.  Do you have a table  that provids the lists for various dropdowns and can you relate them to values in the previous column?

Comment: Thanks Cooper. What I want is a lookup table with several hundred laptop brands and makes as well as key information to extract. From this lookup list, I want a table that the client will fill out based on the Hardware they use using the conditional data validation. Currently, it works by having a separate table for Apple Dell etc.  and then using the index to look up the correct table, but ideally, I would have all the brands in one table with column A dictating the Make, column B the model which can then be extracted into our table with data validation. Hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

If your script was working then this should work as well.  It's a bit more compact and makes better use of the event object.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == "Hardware" && e.range.columnStart == 2 && e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.range.rowStart < 20) {
    e.range.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();
    var makes = sh.getRange(29, 1, 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
    var idx = makes.indexOf(e.value);
    if (~idx) {
      var validationRange = sh.getRange(30, idx + 1, sh.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      e.range.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
    }
  }
}
```